# How to simulate bloom of light in fog

Tags: lighting

How would you recreate something like the photo below in Blender? I'm refereeing to the effect generated by the lights and the fog. I know that this effect is rather intensified/created by the exposure time of the photo being really long, despite this, could you still in Blender do something similar? (targeting Cycles and a single image render)

[image]

Comment: +1 I'm glad that you want to recreate that image. It's quite scary to have traffic lights which show red, yellow and green at the same time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion it has nothing to do with exposure time, exposure time creates streaks when the light object is moving, which is not the case here.

You could do it with some *Spot* lights within a fog, created by volumetrics: Create a cube and give it a *Principled Volume* node plugged into the *Volume* input of its *Output*. Keep the *Density* value of the *Principled Volume* very low. Put the spots inside the cube:

[image]

In *Eevee* it will need some additional tweakings: in the *Render* panel, increase the *Sampling* values, and under Volumetrics, lower down the *Tile Size* and increase the *Samples* values to have a better quality).

But volumetrics are heavy to calculate, if you want a lighter solution, you can create a cone for each light beam and give it the following material: Use a mix between emission and transparency with a *Layer Weight* as factor to create transprency on the borders, and use a *Separate XYZ* to create transparency on the length. In *Eevee* don't forget to choose *Alpha Blend* in the material Settings:

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you I will give it a try!

Comment: It might be more practical to use an Empty ➝ Cube for the volume.

Comment: @ Joachim, what do you mean? You can't give any material to an empty